# I am trying to install react-native but keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, react-native

I want to start developing native apps with react-native and i am also using VScode as my code editor, i keep running in to error when trying to start my project using this command "expo init First project", so how do you think i can overcome this error

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: You have to write more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should first install the expo-cli with `npm install --global expo-cli` before starting a project

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Node.js installed run the following command:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

After successfully installing the Expo CLI you can initialize a brand new project by running the following command:

```
expo init <name of project goes here>
```

```
cd <name of project goes here>
npm start
```

Below is an example of how this will work:

```
expo init my-todo-app
cd my-todo-app
npm start
```